# Visa exemption for non-tourist US visa holder

Tags: visas, visa-free-entry

What countries grant visa exemptions or simplified visa procedures for holders of valid US visas, specifically of US visas of category other than B (tourist)? I know Mexico is one of them, so are there any other countries that do so?

Comment: Here on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B_visa#Use_for_other_countries)

Comment: @SheikPaul I meant US visas of all categories not just B - edited my question to clarify this.

Comment: Surely different countries have different policies with respect to US visa types.  A comprehensive list of countries that grant immigration benefits to US visa holders with all types of US visas and the corresponding immigration benefit associated with that type of visa in that country would be, I think, too cumbersome, implying that the question is too broad.

Comment: @XuanruiQi What's the purpose of your question? Nobody is going to get you a list of all countries who accept all US visas.